# ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, xenial, apps not start

Tags: appmenu, startup-applications

In last some days apps not start neither from Menu nor from tray icons nor from /usr/share/applications.
There are some exceptions: LXTerminal, PacManFM, Task Manager, Monitor Settings...
But about 90% of apps not start only the mouse icon changes to wait for about 30 secs.
Examples: Chromium Web Browser, Software Updater, Calculator, Disyplays, Synaptic Package Manager(only auth popup shows up), System Settings...

Comment: What did you do with your system before this situation occur? Are you tried to check the file system using `fsck` according to type of file system you have?

Comment: I'd also suggest starting apps from a terminal as that often reveals error messages that provide useful clues.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what was it just before the problem started:
1) a new graphics card was installed
2) ubuntu software updates (via Software Updater)
This is a Virtual Box, and I do clones sometimes, and a prev clone is working fine, but I don't want to change back to that.

Comment: from terminal e.g.: chromium-browser , nothing happens, get back the prompt

Comment: fsck:
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda1 is mounted.
WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you ***WILL***
cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.
Here I did'n dare hit Y. It is a normal message of fsck?